# Is there a way to discover what image was used to create a VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm experimenting with my 60 day trial by setting up a chain of VMs with different specs to allow me to upgrade a Vtiger installation from its very old code to current spec.
As I've been create and delete happy I can't recall which image I used for a particular VM and now I'd like to make a fresh VM from the same image.

I was expecting to find a creation log for each VM but haven't yet and I can't see a relevant gcloud command.
I've checked the SSH login screen and I've scoured the web GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the image used by issuing the following command:

```
gcloud compute disks describe YOUR_INSTANCE'S_DISK_NAME
```

You will then see the sourceImage and the sourceImageId.